# Converting coordinates from meters to degrees in OpenLayers?

Tags: coordinate-system, openlayers, convert

There are coordinates:

```
const coordinates = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates(); // [6133089.722279472, 6765816.347945557, 100.7113838]
```

How to convert them into degree?

I have tried this:

```
export function projectionTransform(
  coordinates: number[],
  from = 'EPSG:4326',
  to = 'EPSG:3857'
) {
  return Proj.transform(coordinates, from, to);
}
```

Initialization map:

```
this.map = new MapOl({
  target: targetId,
  layers: baseLayersGroup,
  controls: [],
  maxTilesLoading: 32,
  view: new View({
    center: centerposiiton,
    zoom,
  }),
});
```

Comment: Original coordinates are not EPSG:4326, so `from = 'EPSG:4326'` is definitely wrong

Comment: So, how it right? from and to?

Comment: I don't know, only you will know which actual Coordinate reference systems you have, and want to convert into, but EPSG:4326 is a degrees latitude/longitude CRS so you should expect the first value to be +/- 90 and second value +/-180, and your values `6133089.722279472, 6765816.347945557` are not that.  Your title says you want to convert from metres to degrees, but if you convert from EPSG:4326 to EPSG:3857 you are going in the opposite direction

Comment: I got coordinates by click on feature, it has meters. I need convert it into degree

Comment: Any ideas, how to do thst?

Comment: If you want to to get complete answer, please edit your question and add code of how you define your map and view.

Comment: I have added, but I think it is unsuful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not setting CRS in your view definition, this means your coordinates are in default `EPSG:3857` CRS.

To get you coordinates in `[lon, lat]` degrees you can use `Proj.toLonLat` method (see https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_proj.html#.toLonLat).

Your code could then look something like this:

```
export function projectionTransform(
  coordinates: number[]
) {
  return Proj.toLonLat(coordinates);
}
```

Comment: So, I got it: `lat
: 
51.79808053099998
lon
: 
55.135973474
z
: 
116.65578492`` is it degree?

Comment: Yes, the first two are in degrees. For the third one, which is height, I do not know why the value was changed, if coordinates are the same as in your question.